# How to run loadrunner to test business processes

Tags: testing, loadrunner, business-process

I'm a newbie to loadrunner, and encountered a problem when using it: I run loadrunner to test one of the business processes just like a WorkFlow something , when the recording work done, the process state is changed to Done, no more existed vie normal browsing, after that, I set 10 Vuser to run the script, of couse they all fail. I know a little thing about the correlation, but I feel it' s not the solution of my situation, what i'm gonna do about it? could you give me some addvice? thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you been through training?

Do you have an assigned mentor for your first year?

Comment: -_-||  I'm acturally a coder, and assigned to test a program written by some other guy, not enough time for me to dig it out, I 'm pressed by boss.....

Comment: Your boss is not the friend of quality in this case or invested in your success.   This is not a class of tools that you can just throw at a person and have any degree of assured success.